# libGDX logging problems

Tags: java, logging, libgdx

I cannot print any message in the LogCat with libGDX using the method:

```
Gdx.app.log(tag, message);
```

In my onCreate method I've set:

```
Gdx.app.setLogLevel(Application.LOG_INFO); //debug or error, same story
```

Render method:

```
public void render() {
   if (loading && assets.update())
      doneLoading();
   Gdx.app.log("application", "loaded");    //not showed
   camController.update();
   Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
   Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);
   Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

   modelBatch.begin(cam);
   modelBatch.render(instances, environment);
   modelBatch.end();
```

}

doneLoading() method:

```
private void doneLoading() {
   I_model = assets.get("data/male_teen.g3db", Model.class);
   I_instance = new ModelInstance(I_model);
   instances.add(I_instance);
   loading = false;
}
```

Suggestions?

Comment: You sure that the render method is called?? Please verify using System.out.printn...... Also check whether you have applied any filter in the log cat.

Comment: The only explanation that I think is possible is that you are filtering out the messages in your IDE.

Comment: @ParasMittal I'm sure render method is called because my class implements ApplicationListener. Besides the model is shown on the screen.

Comment: @Tenfour04 in the LogCat saved filter I can see "all messages (no filter)" and the "session filter" for the application. Can't see any log message in both of them, neither using System.out.print().

Comment: Try set "section filter" to null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've deleted the filter that is created automatically by Eclipse. Cleaned the project and reinstalled on the device. Now it works.